# checkbox - checked or unchecked with jQuery and MySQL

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, checkbox

I am currently creating a system where it has to be possible to check/uncheck a checkbox. Everytime it changes status I need jQuery to make an AJAX call to a page, that updates the database.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For example you can do it like this:

First you have to look if the checkbox is checked:

```
$("#yourSelector").live("click", function(){
        var id = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
            // checkbox is checked -> do something
        } else {
            // checkbox is not checked -> do something different
        }
});
```

You can load specific content via Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "xml",
                url: "path/to/file.php",
                data: "function=loadContent&id=" + id,
                success: function(xml) {
                    // success function is called when data came back
                    // for example: get your content and display it on your site
                }
});
```

Comment: Remember that you'll need to declare the variable `id` somewhere before assigning it a value. And, if using [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) it's always worth specifying the [radix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix): `parseInt($(this).val(), 10);`

Answer (score 10):

Which bit are you stuck on? You should probably have something like this...

```
$('#myCheckbox').click(function() {
    var checked = $(this).is(':checked');

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: myUrl,
        data: { checked : checked },
        success: function(data) {
            alert('it worked');
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('it broke');
        },
        complete: function() {
            alert('it completed');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Well i'm stuck on the click-thing. I have read that it is bad to use click with checkbox. And when I try to perform alerts when the checkbox is clicked it does not alert anything - so I'm not sure, that it is working :s

Answer (score 2):

Detect if checkbox is checked:

```
if ( $('#id').is(':checked') ) { }
```

This can be executed in a function that is triggered by "onchange" event.

```
function checkCheckboxState() {

    if ( $('#id').is(':checked') ) { 

        // execute AJAX request here

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this probably?

```
$('.checkbox').click(function (){
    var val = $(this).is(':checked');
    $.load('url_here',{status:val});
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="bar" class="checkIt"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.checkIt').bind('click', function() {
        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
            // checkbox is checked
        } else {
            // checkbox is not checked
        }
    });
</script>
```

You can now have more than one checkbox.